# Asymptotic running time of loop

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

```
function func5(n) 
   s = 0; 
   for i = 1 to 3n^2 do
   for j = 1 to floor(2n^3/i) do   
   s=s + i − j;  
   return(s);
```

What is the asymptotic running time of the above algorithms in theta notation?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you should make some attempt to solve the task yourself. This is not a site meant to provide entire solutions to given problems.

Comment: What is `^`? Power or XOR?

Answer (score 0):

Expressing this in summation form:

[image]

The summation term is a *harmonic series*. From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) it can be approximated as:

[image]

Where `gamma` is the *Euler-Mascheroni* constant (~0.577). Therefore the overall complexity is:

[image]